# Why do my HTTP GET requests start timing out?

Tags: java, rest, http, socket-timeout-exception

I am using the `org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate` in the client side to execute rest calls targeted on a restful webservice running on Cent OS host.

I am seeing a strange behavior where when a series of these calls are made I get a connect timeout error saying

> "java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out"

A noticeable thing here is that the http call fails allways after at least one asynch http call is made. On a failure the http call is tried multiple times with fix 5 sec wait time.

Below are the headers that get passed in the http calls -

```
[Accept: application/json
, Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
, Accept-Language: en_US
, API-Version: 100
, X-Request-ID: a99ccd66-5172-4056-a319-4e2e2614aff6
, X-User-Waiting: false
, Connection: Close
, Content-Length: 2015
]
```

The http call doesn't look to be even hitting the server. What am I missing here? Is there a header I need to set differently?

Answer (score 1):

One likely explanation is that the server is rate-limiting traffic to the API by limiting the number of connections it will accept from your IP address within an interval of time. The clue is that you say the first *n* requests will succeed before the *n + 1*'th request mysteriously fails.

If this rate-limiting is being done at the firewall level, the HTTP request would be dropped before ever reaching the Web server and thus you would not see it in its logs.

It sounds like you have some control over the server. If you do, try running (as root):

`iptables -vL INPUT`

If you see a entry in the "destination" column that looks something like

```
tcp dpt:http state NEW limit: avg 10/min burst 5
```

or a pair of entries like

```
tcp dpt:http state NEW recent: UPDATE seconds: 60 hit_count: 10 name: DEFAULT side: source 
tcp dpt:http state NEW recent: SET name: DEFAULT side: source
```

then this is most likely what's happening, and you will need to either accept this limit or modify your server's firewall rules.

If you *don't* have control over the server, check the documentation for the API you're using to see if it enforces rate limits on clients. It could be the server returns headers in its responses ([as Twitter does](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/rate-limiting/1.1)) to help clients predict when they're about to hit their limit.